# How to use distinct value of a list for a each process in python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a list such as 
`foo = ['battery', 'correct', 'horse', 'staple']`
Now i am using multiprocessing and i am using one value from list in each process. Now i want my process to not to use a value which is already being used by another process. If there are 4 value in a list then there will be at max 4 processes. How can i achieve this.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `multiprocessing.Pool`'s `map` method?

Comment: Read through the documentation, it's pretty good: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: im new multiprocessing so i dont know what multiprocessing.pool is ., ill look into it

Comment: Have you written any code? Because it's not clear how you want to use the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding some line of code. Hope you can find it useful.

```
def your_function(name):
    print('hello', name)                   


from multiprocessing import Process` #import multiprocessing
foo = ['battery', 'correct', 'horse', 'staple']# your lis
processVar = ['t1','t2','t3','t4'] # You can create dynamic variable as per your need
for var,fooItems in zip(processVar,foo):
    var = Process(target=your_function, args=(fooItems,))
    var.start()
```